# How to correctly detect file encodings with LispWorks?

Tags: encoding, stream, common-lisp, lispworks

I am trying to detect file encoding using LispWorks.

LispWorks should be capable of such functionality, see [External Formats and File Streams](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-203.htm).

[Note: details based on @rainer-joswig  and @svante comments]

[`system:*file-encoding-detection-algorithm*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-1347.htm) is set to its default,

```
(setf system:*file-encoding-detection-algorithm*
      '(find-filename-pattern-encoding-match
       find-encoding-option
       detect-utf32-bom
       detect-unicode-bom
       detect-utf8-bom
       specific-valid-file-encoding
       locale-file-encoding))
```

And also,

```
;; Specify the correct characters
(lw:set-default-character-element-type 'cl:character)
```

Some verifiable files available here:

- [UCS-2 and UTF-8](http://www.humancomp.org/unichtm/unichtm.htm)
- [LATIN-1: windows-1252-2000.ucm](https://ssl.icu-project.org/repos/icu/data/trunk/charset/data/ucm/)

`UNICODE` and `LATIN-1` are properly detected

```
;; UNICODE
;; http://www.humancomp.org/unichtm/tongtwst.htm
(with-open-file (ss "/tmp/tongtwst.htm")
  (stream-external-format ss))
;; => (:UNICODE :LITTLE-ENDIAN T :EOL-STYLE :CRLF)

;; LATIN-1
(with-open-file (ss "/tmp/windows-1252-2000.ucm")
  (stream-external-format ss))
;; => (:LATIN-1 :EOL-STYLE :LF)
```

Detecting `UTF-8` does *not* work right away,

```
;; UTF-8 encoding
;; http://www.humancomp.org/unichtm/tongtwst8.htm
(with-open-file (ss "/tmp/tongtws8.htm")
  (stream-external-format ss))
;; => (:LATIN-1 :EOL-STYLE :CRLF)
```

Adding `UTF-8` to `*specific-valid-file-encodings*` makes it work,

```
(pushnew :utf-8 system:*specific-valid-file-encodings*)
;; system:*specific-valid-file-encodings*
;; => (:UTF-8)

;; http://www.humancomp.org/unichtm/tongtwst8.htm
(with-open-file (ss "/tmp/tongtws8.htm")
  (stream-external-format ss))
;; => (:UTF-8 :EOL-STYLE :CRLF)
```

But now same `LATIN-1` file as above *is detected as UTF-8*,

```
(with-open-file (ss "/tmp/windows-1252-2000.ucm")
  (stream-external-format ss))
;; => (:UTF-8 :EOL-STYLE :LF)
```

Pushing `LATIN-1` to `*specific-valid-file-encodings*` as well,

```
(pushnew :latin-1 system:*specific-valid-file-encodings*)
;; system:*specific-valid-file-encodings*
;; => (:LATIN-1 :UTF-8)

;; This one works again
(with-open-file (ss "/tmp/windows-1252-2000.ucm")
  (stream-external-format ss))
;; => (:LATIN-1 :EOL-STYLE :LF)

;; But this one, which was properly detected as `UTF-8`,
;; is now detected as `LATIN-1`, *which is wrong.*
(with-open-file (ss "/tmp/tongtws8.htm")
  (stream-external-format ss))
;; => (:LATIN-1 :EOL-STYLE :CRLF)
```

What I am doing wrong?

How can I correctly detect file encoding using LispWorks?

Comment: I use: `(pushnew :utf-8 system:*specific-valid-file-encodings*)`

Comment: Doing that I get `(with-open-file (ss "/lisp/test-utf8.log") (stream-external-format ss))`

`Error: External format (:UTF-8 :EOL-STYLE :CRLF) produces characters of type SIMPLE-CHAR, which is not a subtype of the specified element-type BASE-CHAR.`

Comment: right, you also need to specify the correct characters. You can do that in WITH-OPEN-FILE and `:element-type`, IIRC. `cl:character` should work. I set it system wide in my `.lispworks` file: `(lw:set-default-character-element-type 'cl:character)`.

Comment: Hmm, you want to experiment a bit with the settings and the function `system:guess-external-format`. Since I don't use windows, I don't see the same effects. A question on the LispWorks mailing list might generate some answers...

Comment: This may be obvious, but there need to be some characters with a code > 127 in your file for such a heuristic to work.

Comment: @RainerJoswig @ svante: Thank you for valuable advice. I have added details based on your comments. Some files are detected fine, some are not. Please see question.

Comment: The `.ucm` file is an ASCII file.  ASCII is a subset of both UTF-8 and Latin-1, so whatever gets checked first is chosen.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Would you like to make a short answer, so I can accept it as best answer? Or I could do it, quoting your comment, if you wish.